# MATLAB Support Package for Arduino® Hardware baud rate change

Tags: matlab, arduino

MATLAB released a Support Package for Arduino® Hardware this September and I am using it with MATLAB r2014a. I am having problems concerning the speed of the communication between MATLAB and Arduino. Does anyone know how can I increase the baud rate? I tried changing it in the arduino.m file but I get the following error :

```
Updating server code on Arduino Uno (COM3). Please wait.
Error using arduino_real_time_plotter (line 1)
Internal error: The initialization of the server code is
incorrect.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Mathworks this is no longer possible in the new MATLAB Support Package for Arduino® Hardware!